# Webpage sort by price dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the filter dropdown menu and select i.e. 'Price High - Low' I want it to display products in order of price, however when I select any option nothing happens, the page remains the same. If I type in the link manually i.e. `main.php?sort=name` then that works.

HTML:

```
<select name="menu" id="drop">
    <option>-- Select a filter --</option>
    <option value="main.php?sort=name">Name A - Z</option>
    <option value="main.php?sort=pasc">Price Low-High</option>
    <option value="main.php?sort=pdesc">Price High-Low</option>    
</select>
```

JS:

```
var sortmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu' );
sortmenu.onchange = function() {
    window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, "_self" );
};
```

Comment: I made a major edit only keeping the relevant bits. If you think I missed something, feel free to roll back, and in that case, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select menu's id is `drop` not `menu`, however your `sortmenu` variable is defined as `document.getElementById( 'menu' )`, but there is no id called `menu` in your code.

So to resolve this, change this...

```
var sortmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu' );
```

...into this...

```
var sortmenu = document.getElementById( 'drop' );
```

Alternatively you could change this...

```
<select name="menu" id="drop">
```

...into this...

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
```

Basically either you rename the id of the select element, or change the id name in the `getElementById` function.